# How can I make for loop wait in each iteration?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, for-loop

I am trying to wait after each for loop using Threads in my application but I have a problem. This for loop has to be executed when the film from URL is playing but...

Unfortunately the loop is executed with pauses that I put into the code and later the film starts with text updated. This should start simultaneously. The for loop and the film. During the film the texts should be  updated one after another.

NOTE: I shorted the ArrayList dict to make code easier to understand.

NOTE2: The app tries to open video file from URL but it gives me a message:
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open (Video URL) : java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: (Video URL).

EDIT: I am putting an entire class code for you.

```
public class Video extends Activity {

    private VideoView videoView;
    private TextView englishTrans1;
    private TextView polishTrans1;
    private TextView englishTrans2;
    private TextView polishTrans2;
    private TextView englishTrans3;
    private TextView polishTrans3;

    int j = 0;
    int i =0;
    public static final String TAG = "My tag";

    ArrayList<Translations> dict = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view1);

        MediaController mMedia = new MediaController(this);

        mMedia.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        mMedia.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mMedia);

        String path1 = (HERE IS VIDEO URL);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path1);

        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.start();

        englishTrans1 = findViewById(R.id.english_trans1);
        polishTrans1 = findViewById(R.id.polish_trans1);

        englishTrans2 = findViewById(R.id.english_trans2);
        polishTrans2 = findViewById(R.id.polish_trans2);

        englishTrans3 = findViewById(R.id.english_trans3);
        polishTrans3 = findViewById(R.id.polish_trans3);

        dict.add(new Translations("kot","cat"));
        dict.add(new Translations("pies","dog"));
        dict.add(new Translations("kawa","coffee"));
        dict.add(new Translations("herbata","tea"));
        dict.add(new Translations("kościół","church"));
        dict.add(new Translations("ślub","wedding"));

        final Handler h = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {

                for(Translations x : dict){

                    try {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        }

                    }catch (InterruptedException e){

                    }
                        switch (j) {
                            case 1: {
                                Log.d(TAG, "First word translated");
                                englishTrans1.setText(x.getEnglishWord());
                                polishTrans1.setText(x.getPolishWord());
                                break;
                            }
                            case 2: {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Second word translated");
                                englishTrans2.setText(x.getEnglishWord());
                                polishTrans2.setText(x.getPolishWord());
                                break;
                            }
                            case 3: {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Third word translated");
                                englishTrans3.setText(x.getEnglishWord());
                                polishTrans3.setText(x.getPolishWord());
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                        if (j < 3) {
                            j++;
                        } else {
                            j = 1;
                        }


                }


            }

        };

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                h.sendEmptyMessage(0);

            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Translations.java class with constructor.

```
public class Translations {

    private String polishWord;
    private String englishWord;

    public Translations(){
    }

    public Translations(String mPolishWord,String mEnglishWord){
        polishWord = mPolishWord;
        englishWord = mEnglishWord;
    }
    public String getPolishWord() {
        return polishWord;
    }

    public void setPolishWord(String polishWord) {
        this.polishWord = polishWord;
    }

    public String getEnglishWord() {
        return englishWord;
    }

    public void setEnglishWord(String englishWord) {
        this.englishWord = englishWord;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding which problem you're trying to solve.  Is the problem that *the loop is executed... and later the film starts with text updated. This should start simultaneously* or is the problem that you're getting a FileNotFound exception and aren't able to play the video at all?

Comment: It is weird because the layout blocks itself, the Logs are being created (so the switch works, right?) and after the switch completes the video starts. Why it does not start simultaneously (the switch loop with layout updated and the video)?

Comment: Are you using MediaPlayer class?  Can you include in your sample code where and how you are starting the video?

Comment: Sample code included @RaceYouAnytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. The issue was that I was trying to sleep the Thread in Handler. The JVM thought that the main thread should be paused, not the "t" Thread. I moved the Thread.sleep() method to run() and the for loop too. I left only switch() in the Handler to change the UI. It works right now.

```
        final Handler h = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {

               Translations x = dict.get(i-1);
                        switch (j) {
                            case 1: {
                                Log.d(TAG, "First word translated");
                                englishTrans1.setText(x.getEnglishWord());
                                polishTrans1.setText(x.getPolishWord());
                                break;
                            }
                            case 2: {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Second word translated");
                                englishTrans2.setText(x.getEnglishWord());
                                polishTrans2.setText(x.getPolishWord());
                                break;
                            }
                            case 3: {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Third word translated");
                                englishTrans3.setText(x.getEnglishWord());
                                polishTrans3.setText(x.getPolishWord());
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                }


            };


        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for(i = 0;i<dict.size();i++) {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                    }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    }

                    if (j < 3) {
                        j++;
                    } else {
                        j = 1;
                    }
                    h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }


            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why loop at all, The "subtitles" as that is what the code snippet is doing, are linked to the video.
What if the person scrubs the film and fast forwards or rewinds, Most subtitle setups have the sentence on screen linked with a timecode for the film, so you then have the subtitle triggered on a change of timecode on the playing video, and pass in the timecode so it will get the sentence for that part of the video and display it on screen.

Comment: For now I don't want the text to be connected to the video time. I understand you and this is true but I need my problem solved just for the mistake that I am doing in this code. This loop is rather than exercise for me than a real problem.

Comment: It looks like you are not doing it on a different thread, and if you are the code is not shown in the question. You need to have the text thread running on a different thread and you have it called a handler, so are you trying to call this every couple seconds?

Comment: Can you look now? I have edited the sample code. @Theresa Forster